# Using flex-wrap on containers with width: 100%

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox, responsive-design

I'm trying to have a form that has inputs for *name* and *lastname*. I'd like my inputs to be inline and also occupy 100% of the available space horizontally, and when there's no sufficient space that they wrap. You can see this working fine in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sbfm9ygo/22/ (the inputs are inline and when you make the screen smaller they wrap automatically).

I can achieve this with flexbox using the `flex-wrap` property **but** only when the width of my elements is not 100%. In the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbfm9ygo/22/), if you uncomment `width: 100%` you'll notice that this no longer works. How can I achieve the functionality showed on the jsfiddle while making my elements take 100% of the available space? I'm trying to do this without using media-queries.

Comment: what is the minimum width of `input` fields, that you want?

Comment: @AjeetEppakayala I think around `150px` would be fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix it using `flex-grow: 1;` instead of `width: 100%`:

```css
.form-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.form-container div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">

  <div>
    <label>Label1</label>
    <input value="input1" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Label2</label>
    <input value="input2" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdo9tfsw/8/).

Answer (score 1):

**`flex`: 1 would divide them in equal and `min-width: 150px;` will prevent `input` to get any lesser in size**

```css
.form-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
}

.form-container div {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 150px;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">

  <div>
    <label >Label1</label>
    <input value="input1"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label >Label2</label>
    <input value="input2"/>
  </div>

</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45n6raho/)**